# Simple Angular code not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

HTML

```
<section ng-app="app">
     <table ng-controller="VoicemailsCtrl">
        <caption>{{test}}</caption>
    </table>
</section>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
              .controller('VoicemailsCtrl', ['$scope', VoicemailsCtrl]);

function VoicemailsCtrl($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.vms = [1,2,3];
    $scope.test = 'this is a test';
}
```

Can be seen at:

http://jsfiddle.net/tx9nbo8g/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed adding 
    `ng-app="app"`
in the section.

Check the updated fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tx9nbo8g/5/)

Apart from this you need to add

> angular 1.2.1

and

> No wrap in head

in framework and extension.
.

Comment: No I did not, it is there,

Comment: It was not there in the original fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, sir. +1 for everyone

Answer (score 2):

Please find below working code :

**Html:**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <section>
        <table ng-controller="VoicemailsCtrl">
            <caption>{{test}}</caption>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>
```

**Js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('VoicemailsCtrl', ['$scope','$http',VoicemailsCtrl]); //You forgot to add $http

function VoicemailsCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.vms = [1,2,3];
    $scope.test = 'this is a test';
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qCsG4WzFc0Irt2RobLoC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-app="app"` on `section` element & also you need to change the script loading option inside your fiddle from OnLoad to `No Wrap in <head/>`

**Markup**

```
<section ng-app="app">
    <table ng-controller="VoicemailsCtrl">
        <caption>{{test}}</caption>
    </table>
</section>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tx9nbo8g/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should have to be changed. You need to tell angular where app is starting. Default `ng-app` is also a valid app declaration.

```
 <section ng-app="MyApp">
         <table ng-controller="VoicemailsCtrl">
            <caption>{{test}}</caption>
        </table>
    </section>
```

In controller

```
 angular.module('MyApp', [])
 .controller('VoicemailsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.vms = [1,2,3];
    $scope.test = 'this is a test';
 }]);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beera/tx9nbo8g/7/)

You should not use global declaration of controller. Its been deprecated in angular `1.3+` versions. You should use `controller` directive to declare a controller.

Comment: The declaration of controller is absolutely fine. Though it will be present in the global namespace but its not deprecated at all. Its still using controller to register a controller.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash, its true. But in angular 1.3+ versions global declaration will not work.

Comment: Can you share an official link? Reason being I am using 1.4.* and using the same way to declare a controller.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash BTW you can get it by your own, but here is a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346238/angularjs-beginner-ng-controller-not-working/31346404#31346404.  Ronnie's comment will make you clear.

Comment: Please check, The code he is referring to do not register the constructor function using module.controller(). Using constructor function directly as controller is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts.